# How to check which image is set to the activity's view?

Tags: android

How can I check what image is on my activity (programmatically)? I want to make a condition: if I have lets say img1, then I want to show a Toast "img1", and if I have img2, then I want to show a Toast "img2". I know there is something like `setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2)`, which does setting an image.

Answer (score 0):

you want to test if your imageView contains an image, then u want to set another

use this if it helps

```
if(imgView.getDrawable().equals(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.id.img1))) {
     //affiche your Toast Here ... Toast ( "img1 displayed ..").show();
     Toast.makeText(this,"image 1 dispayed ...",3000).show();
}
else if(imgView.getDrawable().equals(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.id.img2))) {
     //affiche your Toast Here ... Toast ( "img2 displayed ..").show();
     Toast.makeText(this,"image 2 dispayed ...",3000).show();
}
```

is that what you want to do ??

Comment: try : if( imageView.getDrawable().equals(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.id.img1) 
or i think u forgot Toast(....).show() ; it happens ;) :D

Comment: i've edited my post , 
if it still doesn't work, post the piece of code here , and i will try to resolve it ;)

Comment: Ya this doesn't work. Even I am trying to get an image associated with an ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the setTag function associated with a view to hold this information,  as in view.setTag("img1")  and you can get back the value as in (String)view.getTag()